# Delete user agent styles

Tags: css, angular, google-chrome, angular-material, styles

Someone know how to delete styles of user agent styles?

[image]

I'm using Angular and Material Angular.

Thanks for all.

Comment: Which style property are you willing to overwrite ?

Comment: All styles.....

Answer (score 1):

If you are not added <!DOCTYPE> in your HTML content, browser gives preference to the *user agent stylesheets* over your css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
---
---
</html>
```

Comment: I have <!DOCTYPE html>